# JQGrid dynamic data loading (JSON)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid, html-helper

I have a JQGrid which I am trying to have load dynamic JSON data (depending on search results). It seems my problem is that I can't get the JSON string in the correct format.

Here's my code:

```
public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {

        DataSet data = (DataSet) TempData["temp"];


        //var rowdata = GetJson(data.Tables[0]);
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = data.Tables[0].Rows.Count,
            page = page,
            records = data.Tables[0].Rows.Count,
            rows = GetJson(data.Tables[0])
        };
        var a = Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return a;

    }

    public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }

}
```

and in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'/Search/GridData/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: @Html.Raw(formatColNames()),
    colModel:@Html.Raw(formatColModel()),
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[5,10,20,50],
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'My first grid'
  }); 
});
```

How can I use the data I'm getting back (from SQL server in the form of a DataSet) and load it into the grid. Assume the columns are formatted correctly (they are). I checked JSONLint and my json is definitely not valid, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are serializing the row data twice. Once in the `GetJson` function, and again when the Json result is created.

I would try returning a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` from the GetJson function, and let `Json(jsonData)` do the serializing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix, I've been staring at code all day :)